# Apache2 reverse-proxy to https 9443

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have a [WSO2 Mashup server](http://wso2.org/project/mashup/2.3.2/docs/quickstart.html).  Normally it is accessed by `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/carbon`

For some reason, I want to set a reverse proxy to access it, so it can be access by `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/carbon`

I have followed the guide from http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy and created a conf file in the `conf.d` folder.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /carbon/ https://127.0.0.1:9443/carbon/
ProxyPassReverse /carbon/ https://127.0.0.1:9443/carbon/


<Location "/carbon">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

I get error 404 if I try `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/carbon`

```
Not Found

The requested URL /carbon was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 125.215.250.19 Port 80
```

Anyway, all I want is to access by https only, but I get error 107 if I try `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/carbon`

```
SSL connection error

Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or  it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are proxying `/carbon/` and accessing `/carbon` which are not the same thing. When accessing a resource that is a directory like `/carbon` a web server will actually send a redirect to `/carbon/` which is probably why you expect it to work as the 9443 server does.

Try accessing `/carbon/` or proxy `/carbon` instead

```
ProxyPass /carbon https://127.0.0.1:9443/carbon
ProxyPassReverse /carbon https://127.0.0.1:9443/carbon
```

Comment: thanks mindthemonkey, but I got this error in apache2 error.log. I think it is relate to the some ssl problem?

    client denied by server configuration: /etc/apache2/htdocs
    client denied by server configuration: /etc/apache2/htdocs
    client denied by server configuration: /etc/apache2/htdocs
    client denied by server configuration: /etc/apache2/htdocs
    SSL Proxy requested for 127.0.1.1:8081 but not enabled [Hint: SSLProxyEngine]
    proxy: HTTPS: failed to enable ssl support for 127.0.0.1:9443 (127.0.0.1)

Comment: @VirtualJasper Yes indeed, you need to add to your config `SSLProxyEngine on`.